# Using CDK, prevent resource in stack from being updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a lambda deployed in a stack, that is referenced via ARN by resources that I do not manage. It is problematic that certain updates to other resources can trigger this lambda to be redeployed. So therefore I would like to put a stack policy in place like [what is described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html#protect-stack-resources-modifying), but from within the CDK project itself. I've looked through the [stack construct's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#example) but don't see any API's exposed. I've also [looked here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) at the actual `Stack` CFN resource, and don't see it as a property you can supply.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say your Lambda resource is "redeployed", what do you mean?  Please add an example of when a downstream resource causes this.

Comment: You would probably need to add a snapshot test to make sure the ARN hasn't changed. I have a feeling this is an XY problem, though.

Comment: @fedonev Like the [page here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html) states under "Replacement". When certain properties get changed, it will replace the resource. I would like to prevent the resource from being replaced.

Comment: @gshpychka. What do you mean by XY problem? Like a "chicken and egg" problem?

Comment: You cannot prevent the resource from being replaced if you update a property that requires replacement. Your only reasonable option is to write unit/snapshot tests that make sure the function is never updated in a way that requires replacement.